Ubuntu 22.04: impossible to zoom in/out with Ctrl + scroll
With many programs (firefox, LibreOffice, a PDF viewer, etc.), when I perform Ctrl + mouse scroll, I expect a zoom in/out. But instead, Ubuntu always performs a "switch workspace" action, as if I scrolled over the "app" icon or the left panel.
This happens only when I am using a mouse. When I perform Ctrl + scroll up/down with the touchpad, it does not do anything (but Ctrl + scroll left/right changes the workspace).
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, which I just installed from scratch.
EDIT: To be more precise, changing /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier to something that does not contain <Control> solves the problem. However, contrary to the previous post, this was the default behavior, so I had to change it (to <Super> in my case).
